# Determining if a powerpoint text box is over the page size

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I've been researching this for a while and have not found any background on whether Powerpoint VBA can determine if an object (text box or table) is outside the bounds of the page dimensions.

The specific application I am trying to manage is when I flow text into a PPT table from Excel, through a find/replace of specific data markers, I don't know the specific dimensions of the text, so I may overflow the page boundary.

I cant shrink the text either, as I have to maintain the design fidelity of the type size.

I would like to try and measure when this overflow happens and use VB to create a new page onto which I can continue to flow my text from Excel.

Right now I am doing this by just limiting the page template to say 15 rows and then manually adjusting over/under flow of the page. Might be my only option, but thought I would pose the question.

Comment: I am taking the page template and fixing it at a set number of rows, then dividing the data I have across the rows (e.g 15 in example below). Then when I fill the last row up, I move the data to the next page.  


    `k = (LastRow / 15) + 1 'divide the rows by 15 (rows that fit on a page)`  
  
  
  
    `If Marker Like "@PROG1.*" Then ' start new row`  
    `If InStr(1, CStr((i - 2) / 15), ".") = 0 Then 'start new page`  
    `k = k + 1 'increment the page counter`  
    `End If`  
    `End If`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TextboxCheck()

Dim shp As Shape
Dim sld As Slide
Dim sldHeight As Long

sldHeight = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
            If shp.Top + shp.Height > sldHeight Then
                'Add your code here for moving the text to a new slide
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
Next sld

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I did not know about `ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight` That should do the trick.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: As long as the textbox is set to grow to accommodate added text, that should work. If not, shp.height etc will give you the size of the text box but not of the text, which might run out of the text box. You can also look at the shp.TextFrame.TextRange.BoundTop, BoundHeight etc.  These give you the actual dimensions of the text, independent of the shape that contains it (or that it spills out of).