# Paste entire row from powerpoint table on one page into another table on prior page

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Related to my question in determining how to see if a shape has overflowed a page boundary ([Determining if a powerpoint text box is over the page size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057246/determining-if-a-powerpoint-text-box-is-over-the-page-size/38057858#38057858))

I need to move rows of a table on one page to the prior page.

Fairly straightforward to determine the rows I need to cut (I've left that part of the code out for brevity). Where I am having a problem is the method of how to paste it back into the table on the prior page (table has same column dimensions).

In the UI, it is as simple as placing the cursor in the first cell of the target row and hitting paste. This completely replicates the column structure of the cut row. In VB, best I can do is paste the entire text of the cut row (all columns) gets into the one cell. I cant seem to get VB code that can replicate what is happening in the UI.  What command am I missing?

```
For y = 2 To c
Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(k + 1).Shapes("ProgTable")
With oSh.Table
    .Rows(y).Select
End With

Windows(1).Selection.Cut
Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(k).Shapes("ProgTable")

With oSh.Table
    .Rows.Add (-1)
    .Cell(oSh.Table.Rows.Count,1)textFrame.TextRange.Paste 'pastes all columns into the one cell
End With


Next y
```

Alternate line of code to paste clipboard that I can't get to work

```
.Rows(oSh.Table.Rows.Count).Cells.Item.Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.PasteSpecial (PpPasteDataType.ppPasteHTML) 
 'does not work, gives compile error on ITEM argument not optional
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pasting in to a `TextRange`, not the table/row itself. There are some funky things in PPT's object model for sure, and some actions which seem like they should be intuitive (copy/paste) often are not. In these cases, the `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMSO` method is usually where I start (also very useful if you're [copying from/between different applications](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1467082%20ExecuteMSO) like Excel>PowerPoint, Word>PowerPoint, etc.)

I did this to test, and it is working as expected, so it should set you on the right track:

```
Sub CopyRowToAnotherTable()

Dim tbl1 As Table
Dim tbl2 As Table
Dim sld1 As Slide
Dim sld2 As Slide
Dim pres As Presentation

Dim shp As Shape

Set pres = ActivePresentation
Set sld1 = pres.Slides(1)
Set sld2 = pres.Slides(2)
Set tbl1 = sld1.Shapes(1).Table
Set tbl2 = sld2.Shapes(1).Table

'Cut the last row from tbl2:
sld2.Select '## Powerpoint requires the slide to be active/view in order to select shapes on the slide
With tbl2
    .Rows(.Rows.Count).Select
    pres.Windows(1).Selection.Cut
End With

'Insert in tbl1
With tbl1
    .Rows.Add -1
    sld1.Select   
    .Rows(.Rows.Count).Select
    pres.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Paste"
End With
End Sub
```

So in your code, I think this should work:

```
With oSh.Table
    '## select the slide:
    .Parent.Parent.Select
    .Rows.Add (-1)
    .Rows(.Rows.Count).Select
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Paste"
End With
```

The tricky part about the `ExecuteMso` method is mainly that it's not well-documented, or it is, but it's hard to *find* the dox, so here is reference from [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185788/how-to-copy-a-chart-from-excel-to-powerpoint/19187572#19187572):

> Documentation on the ExecuteMso method:
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419.aspx
>
> Downloadable document containing the idMSO parameters for each Office
>   Application:
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6627

Comment: Thank you! I saw that commandbar feature but didn't really now how to implement it within the context of the page. Very helpful.  And I am glad I am not crazy that this was much harder that it felt like it needed to be.